# Changing the recurring frequency of a PayPal Subscription Button when using drop down options

Tags: button, paypal, subscription

Is there any way to change the recurring billing frequency with drop down options for subscription purchases? We need to be able to change our PayPal recurring options from weekly to once every 2 weeks. each of our drop down options have different prices. It's a single item, but with different weight options and each option is priced differently.

There was a very good answer to modifying the time intervals for subscription billing with PayPal buttons on a single item purchase at: [How to implement a quarterly subscription PayPal button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606430/how-to-implement-a-quarterly-subscription-paypal-button)

But it didn't show a way to do that with a drop down option, subscription purchase.

Answer (score 0):

In order to adjust the frequency and amount intervals simultaneously (with a single dropdown selection), you would need to use either client-side javascript, or server-side code triggered by your own form that then redirects.

If they can change independently, i.e. the customer is receiving the same item/service and same price at either 1-week or 2-week intervals, then you can easily extend:

```
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="W">
```

to something like:

```
<select name="p3>
    <option value="1">1 week</option>
    <option value="2">2 weeks</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="W">
```